# asp.net gridview display one or two rows per record based on dropdownlist selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net gridview which displays two rows for each record, using the following code below (example).

However using a dropdownlist which is on the top of the page, based on its selection (1 or 2)  I want the gridview to update itself on the following way:

option 1 = display two rows per record.

option 2 = display only one row per record (second table row shown on code below I don't want it to be shown when Option 2 is selected.

UPDATE:
Selecting the dropdownlist option and making it work is fine, I don't have a problem there, but I need to know how to manipulate the gridview to display one or two rows per record. So basically how can I (with code) change the format of the gridview from 1 to 2 rows.
Obviously there is the option of using two gridviews and show the one needed based on your selection, but I prefer to use one gridview only (if that's possible).

```
 <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPN" runat="server" Text="Project Name" style "color:white;" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="PN"  tabindex="1000" ></asp:LinkButton><br />
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="S_PN" CssClass="FilterField" ></asp:TextBox>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
           <table  >
              <tr>
                 <td class="STD_normal" style="width:150px; font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("PN")%>
                    </td>                                                    
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="STD_Normal_Grey" style="width:150px"><%#Eval("DD", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%> </td>
              </tr>
          </table>                                              
       </ItemTemplate>                                                              
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: manipulating under dropdownlist (selectedindexhanged, something like that), but first set for both `tr` `id` and `runat="server"`. depend on selection show or hide row (display:none; or display:block;).

Comment: @nelek, your table tr id manipulation sounds like what I am looking for. Could you elaborate (example) on how to do that ? Sorry I am a beginner on asp.net.

Comment: answer provided. I hope so it will help You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is code based on one of my database, just change parameters (this is *server side* example, someone else provide here client side example) :

aspx :

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlChoice" AutoPostBack="true">
       <asp:ListItem Text="One row"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Two rows"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <br /><br />
      <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdInfo" DataSourceID="sqlInfo">
       <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
         <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPN" runat="server" Text="Project Name" style="color:white;" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="PN"  tabindex="1000" ></asp:LinkButton><br />
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="S_PN" CssClass="FilterField" ></asp:TextBox>
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <table>
           <tr><td runat="server" id="tdFirst" class="STD_normal" style="width:150px; display:block; font-weight:bold"><%# Eval("PNaziv")%></td></tr>
           <tr><td runat="server" id="tdSecond" class="STD_Normal_Grey" style="width:150px; display:none;"><%#Eval("PMesto")%></td></tr>
          </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDFConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT PNaziv,PMesto FROM Partneri ORDER BY PNaziv;" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code behind (vb.net)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ddlChoice_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlChoice.SelectedIndexChanged
        grdInfo.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub grdInfo_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdInfo.RowCreated
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim td As HtmlTableCell = e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("tdSecond")
            If ddlChoice.SelectedIndex = 0 Then td.Style("display") = "none" Else td.Style("display") = "block"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Like I wrote in comment, I set to each `td` `id` and `runat="server"`. Dropdownlist must have `AutoPostBack="true"`.

Now, on every `SelectedIndexChanged` must bind Your grid and on every created row find `HtmlTableCell`, now, control (it's `td`) and based on selected index show or hide second `td`. But, under `style` of every `td` I put `display:block/none;` depend of row.

When You start webapp only one row will be visible, and after that, depend of dropdownlist choice.

In this example that table is in first column (`Dim td As HtmlTableCell = e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("tdSecond")`)... You have to change that `.e.Row.Cells(x)...`; where *x* is Your column index.

**Update :** You not define prog.language so bellow code is in `c#` (converted from vb.net using online conversion tool, sorry I programming in vb.net)

```
private void ddlChoice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    grdInfo.DataBind();
}

private void grdInfo_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        HtmlTableCell td = e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("tdSecond");
        if (ddlChoice.SelectedIndex == 0)
            td.Style("display") = "none";
        else
            td.Style("display") = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**Client Side**

One way would be to use JavaScript or jQuery to show/hide the second row. For this, I recommend replacing the table with `<div>`'s and adding the class to the `div` tag instead of the `td` tag, or splitting out the tables, as shown in the Server Side example.

Here's a jQuery example:

```
$("#ddl").change(function() {
    if($('#ddl option:selected').val() == 1) {
        $('STD_Normal_Grey').show();
    } else {
        $('STD_Normal_Grey').hide();
    }
}
```

**Server Side**

Here's another example showing a server side option, as well as how you might be able to split out the tables to make controlling the display a bit easier:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="STD_normal" style="width:150px; font-weight:bold">  
            <%#Eval("PN")%>
        </td>                                                    
     </tr>
 </table>
 <table style="display:<%# DdlVal == "1" ? "inline-block" : "none" %>;">
     <tr>
         <td class="STD_Normal_Grey" style="width:150px">
             <%#Eval("DD", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Then, in your code behind:

```
protected string DdlVal
{
    get { return ddl.SelectedValue; }
}
```

This would require the DropDownList to post back, whereas the Client Side solution would not, making the Client Side solution much faster.

Comment: +1 for server side. btw. instead two tables You can use Your code on `td` of second row. Excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

with a dropdownlist you could use the OnSelectedIndexChanged function. like this:

```html
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDemo" on SelectedIndexChanged="ddlDemo_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">one</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="2">tow</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and in the code you could play with it:

```html
    Protected Sub ddlDemo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim selectedValue As Integer = ddlDemo.SelectedValue

        If ddlDemo.SelectedValue = 1 Then

            ' do something

        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The code you mention I already have and works fine. My question was how to change the gridview to display one or two rows per record shown. I will ammend question to avoid further confusion.